# Concatenate a constant array is implementation independent?

Tags: c

I want to know if   have in the ISO specification that a concatenation of a constant array is implementation dependent or not? If it is depends on implementation, could you tell me which compiler does not concatenate?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char *a = "concatenate"
              "this array";
    puts(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a standard feature, but it has nothing to do with constant arrays. It only works for string literals.

The C standard defines a number of "translation phases". Phase 6 is:

> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

See e.g. **5.1.1.2 Translation phases** in [this draft standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).

Comment: Note that this concatenation takes place at compile time.

Comment: Well, yes. Compilation *is* translation (from one programming language to another). If you want to be more specific, the first 6½ phases are preprocessing, the second half of phase 7 is compilation proper, and phase 8 is linking.